# php scraping with DomDocument

Tags: php

i am trying to get `albumid's value (20316543)` from this div but i can't seem to figure him out a way to do this... this is what i have so far.

```
$file = file_get_contents('https://somesite.com');
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$data = $xpath->query("//div[@class='play']");
$ttt = $dom->saveHTML($data);
print_r($data);
```

the html code

```
<div class="overlay-actions">
                        <div class="overlay-action-buttons">
                            <button class="play" onclick="Analytics.logAndSendEventToGA('album:play-all',['albumid','20316543']);Content.playAllSongs('#play-2020', true, 0, true);">Play</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There probably other ways of doing the same, but try this:

```
$string = <<<XML
[your html snippet]
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$result = $xml->xpath("//div//div/button/@onclick");
$left = explode (",[",$result[0])[1];
$target = explode("])",$left)[0];
echo ($target);
```

Output:

```
'albumid','20316543'
```